# Topology induced by semi-norm and P-topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $V$ be an abstract vector space over $F$ and $P$ a family of semi-norms on $V$. We can define a topology on $V$ by declaring its base to consist of subsets of $V$ of the form
$\{v\in V | p_1(v−x)<\varepsilon \land\cdots \land p_n(v−x)<\varepsilon\}$.
Does this topology conincide with the smallest topology which make each seminorm continuus?

---

I asked my teacher and he advised me to be careful because the two topologies aren't the same in a general case. In fact the P topology is the intersection of inverse-images of the cylinders $]-\infty,a[$ but the initial topology is the inverse image of all open sets. So could you show me the proof and I could show him where he is wrong ?

Comment: Two steps: a) that topology makes the $p_i$ continuous, b) every topology making all $p_i$ continuous contains all the basis sets as defined above.

Comment: Thanks! But i don't see clearly how the P-topology could makes the p_i continuous since we just have the $p_i{-1}]- \infty, \varepsilon[$ as open sets and not all the $p_i^{-1}(O)$ with O open set of R.

Comment: That's one of the places where it's better to show that a map is continuous at every point. The triangle inequality makes it short and sweet.